# Auto response to calendar invite in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar, auto-reply

Is it possible to set up auto reply to calendar invite in Outlook without auto accepting/rejecting an invite? I'm looking for a simple response to simply tell the sender that I'm not using that calendar and they should send the invite to another address (unfortunately I cannot simply forward the invite myself to my another address).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I noticed that you want to aet up auto reply to calendar reply in Outlook to tell the sender  to send to another address, it's suggested that you could create a rule to do this. For specific steps, please refer to:

1.Create an email template(New message>type the words you want to reply>File>Save as);

[image]

2.File>Info>Manage Rules & Alerts>New rule…>***Apply rule on messages I receive***;

3.Under Select condition(s), choose ***Which is a meeting invitation or update***>Next;

[image]

4.Under Step1:Select action(s), choose ***reply using a specific template***, then under step 2, click on ***a specific template*** and choose the template you created;

[image]

5.Next>Next>Finish>Ok.

Then when others send meeting request to this address, your address will send an auto reply without auto accepting/rejecting an invite.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.